# Django Authentication and Permissions: Snippets visible only to the creator

Tags: python, django, authentication, permissions, code-snippets

So in the tutorial for authentication and permissions:

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/

All user can see all snippets but it only allows the user to edit their own snippets.

But I want to tweak the program a little bit into:

The user can only see their own snippets. Snippets that are created by others are not visible.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Take a look at [filtering querysets](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-the-current-user). In short, you'll have to write your own `get_queryset` method to only return results associated with the logged in user.